# Gruff Bar Graph Data in array,

Tags: ruby, gruff

I need a Bar Graph in Gruff with two Bars.

For two subjects, I loop through to get the values for activity and grade :

```
sub = ["English", "Maths"]

activity = []
grade = []    

sub.each do |sub|
  activity.push(sub["activity"].to_i)
  grade.push(sub["grade"].to_i)
end
```

Now, I am using these values for my Bar Graph.

```
g = Gruff::Bar.new('500x250')
g.maximum_value = 100 
g.minimum_value = 0
g.y_axis_increment = 15
g.data( "Activity", activity.inspect)
g.data( "Summative", grade.inspect)
g.labels = {0 => 'English', 1 => 'Language II'}
g.write('images/overall_score.png')
```

But, this throws an error " comparison of String with 0 failed". I need the data to be printed as

```
g.data( "Activity", [10,20])

puts activity.inspect prints the array as above ex: [10,20]
```

Looks like the values are treated as strings. What should I do to resolve this.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `inspect` method returns `String`. I think you should just pass your arrays to `data` method like this:

```
g.data("Activity", activity)
g.data("Summative", grade)
```